# Looking for better/elegant solution to appendTo DIVs with jquery in listings

Tags: jquery, html, appendto

I have been teaching myself JS and Jquery primarily for GM scripts (im not a programmer by day) and tried to come up with a solution to append a DIV to another DIV for every single listing on autotrader.com.  They are siblings under multiple parents.  The full code is here http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/83865 and working.

I came up with this:

```
var counter=0;
$('.dealer-info').each(function(){
$(this).appendTo($('.car-info')[counter]);
counter=counter+1;
});
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Any advice would be appreciated as i want my code to be simpler.

Regards,
anthony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) provides the index as the first variable to the callback function, so you can do this:

```
$('.dealer-info').each(function(i) {
  $('.car-info').eq(i).append(this);
});
```

Since [`.appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) just gets flipped around to [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) internally it's less wasteful and a bit easier on the eyes to do it this way using [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) to get the item at that index.

To be more performant, you should keep a reference to `.car-info` outside the loop, like this:

```
var cars = $('.car-info');
$('.dealer-info').each(function(i) {
  cars.eq(i).append(this);
});
```

Comment: @7null - Welcome :)  Be sure to accept answers on this and future questions as you go via the check-mark beside whichever helped you most :)

Answer (score 0):

So you want to append each element with class "dealer-info" to each element with the class "car-info"?

Does `$(".dealer-info").appendTo($(".car-info"));` not do this?

Comment: I tried that and really hoped that would work but it takes all 15 .dealers divs on the page and appends to each .car - so i get 15 divs in each .car.

Answer (score 0):

Along the lines of your code, but a little bit more jQuery way. Haven't tried this, but should work fine.

```
$('.dealer-info').each(function(index, value){
     $(this).appendTo($('.car-info').eq(index));
});
```